# $NL$ Leaf languages and $PSPACE$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines, space-complexity, complexity-classes

I am reading Papadimitriou's *Computational Complexity* and got stuck on part d) of the following exercise (pg. 505)

> 20.2.14 A panorama of complexity classes. ... A language $L \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$  will be called a leaf language. Let A and R be two disjoint leaf languages (the accepting and rejecting leaf language, respectively). Now, any two such languages define a complexity class: Let C[A, R] be the class of all languages L such that there is a (standardized) nondeterministic Turing machine N with the following property: $x \in L$ if and only if $N (x) \in A,$ and $x \notin L$ if and only if $N(x) \in R.$
> ... Show that, if $A, R \in NL,$ then $C[A, R] \subseteq PSPACE.$

How does one show this? I thought there'd be a way to use the result $AP = PSPACE$ directly but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are omitting some very important details. In the exercise, the Turing machine $N$ is required to halt on all its possible computation paths using exactly $p(n)$ steps, where $n$ is the size of the input, and $p(n)$ is upper bounded by a polynomial.
Moreover, each non-deterministic choice is labelled as either $0$ or $1$, which induces an order on the computation paths and hence on the leaves of the computation tree (the $\ell$-th computation path corresponds to the non-deterministic choices given by the binary representation of $\ell$). Each of the leaves is also labelled with either $0$ or $1$ (e.g., for reject/accept). The output $N(x)$ of the execution of $N$ on $x$ is the binary string in $\{0,1\}^{p(n)}$ that corresponds the labels of the leaves, in the order discussed above.

Now we can actually tackle the exercise.
Since $A$ and $R$ are in $NL$, there must be some non-determistic Turing machines $T_A, T_B$ that decide $A$ and $B$, respectively, and use space $O(\log n)$.

Given a language $L \in C[A,R]$, we can show that $L \in \mathsf{PSPACE}$ by providing a Turing machine $T^*$ that takes an input $x$ and decides whether  $x \in L$ using at most polynomial amount of space.

The Turing machine $T^*$ first computes the number of steps $p(|x|)$ taken by $N(x)$ (we can simply simulate one computation path of $N(x)$).
Then $T^*$ simulates two parallel execution of $T_A$ and $T_B$ on the string $y=N(x)$. Since we cannot explicitly generate $y$ (which has length $2^{p(n)}$), we also "simulate" the views that $T_A$ and $T_B$ have over the contents of their tape. Whenever $T_A$ or $T_B$ want to write to a location $\ell$ of their simulated tape, we store the index $\ell$ and the written symbol (possibly replacing the previous symbol stored in $\ell$) in the tape of $T^*$. Whenever $T_A$ or $T_B$ want to read a location $\ell$ of their simulated tape, we first check if $\ell$ was previously written to. If that's the case we answer with the symbol we previously stored. If $\ell$ was never written to, then either we return the blank tape symbol (if $\ell > 2^{p(n)}$) or we return the $\ell$-th symbol of $y$ (when $\ell \le 2^{p(n)}$). To compute the $\ell$-th symbol of $y$ we can simply simulate the $\ell$-th computaton path of $N(x)$.

Notice that the size of the (simulated) input to the simulated versions of $T_A$ and $T_B$ is $|y| = 2^{p(n)}$ yet, since $T_A$ and $T_B$ use logarithmic space, there are at most $O(\log 2^{p(n)}) = O(p(n))$ distinct locations that are written to (which $T^*$ needs to keep track of).

Eventually, one of $T_A(N(x))$ and $T_B(N(x))$ must accept. In the former case $T^*$ also accepts, while in the latter case $T^*$ rejects.